# Html template not printing formatting or image to pdf

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am using the html templating function in app script to create a draft email and pdf document. All of the formatting is showing in the email, but in the pdf a lot of it is missing.

My aim is to show a logo in the formatted pdf and email.
I started by trying to include an image and failed. I cannot get an image to show in either location as part of the existing template (although following the the Google developer info I can get the image into the email/pdf if I use only the image as a blob source, which means I can't include anything else).

My next thought was to build the logo directly in the html file. This fails as I cannot get the background colour to print to the pdf.

I have checked the developers section at Google and the q&as here as well as doing several general web searches.
Things I've checked after reading those:
All formatting is inline.
The template is called and evaluated before creating the output.
The image is shared.

I'm a beginner so I've been trying everything in the hopes of finding a solution. I've left a few different methods in so you can see what I've tried.

If anyone can shed light on what I'm getting wrong I will be really grateful.

**Server Side Code**

```js
 function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
}

function getImageUrl(){
 //this is code I copied to encode as base64 to use with html img but the base64 encode/decode wasn't working for me.
  //var album = GET https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums/{albumId};
  var photosUrl = "https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipMkQrHJPYe935uC-Rap5qVqNaLdUs6rp38yVaw";
  var htmlImage = '<img src="data:image/pgn; base64,'+ photosUrl + '" />' 

  var driveUrl = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/10OgwTmtVp5yDKHdC7P1K2KBEMuEbn6YW/view?usp=sharing";
  var imgId = DriveApp.getFileById('10OgwTmtVp5yDKHdC7P1K2KBEMuEbn6YW');
  var imgType = imgId.getMimeType();

  var imgPng = imgId.getAs('image/png'); //image as png
  var imgBlob1 = imgId.getBlob(); //image as blob
  var imgHtml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(photosUrl).getContent(); // image as html
  var tmpHtml = HtmlService.createTemplate(imgHtml);
  var contHtml = tmpHtml.getRawContent();

  Logger.log('imgType = ' + imgType + '\n imgBlob1  = ' + imgBlob1);

  //create draft and save as pdf
  var createDraft = function myGet() {
   var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('text');
   return temp.evaluate();
  }

  var draft = createDraft();
  var content = draft.getContent();
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(content, 'text/html').getAs('application/pdf').setName('text for image');

  DriveApp.createFile(blob);

 // create draft email 
  var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = 'test';
  var body = 'this is a test';
  var options = {htmlBody: content};

GmailApp.createDraft(recipient, subject, body, options);
}
```

**CSS Code**

```css
<style>body {
  color: blue;
}

</style>
```

**HTML Template**

```html
 <br>
  include image from Drive with img tags and url<br>
  1 <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=10OgwTmtVp5yDKHdC7P1K2KBEMuEbn6YW" />
  <br>
  <br>
  include contHtml (templated blob)<br>
  1 <?! contHtml ?><br>
  <br>
  include imgPng from script with jquery<br>
  1 <? imgPng ?><br>
  2 <?! imgPng ?><br>
  3 <?= imgPng ?><br>
  <br>
  include htmlImage from script with jquery
  1 <? htmlImage ?><br>
  2 <?! htmlImage ?><br>
  3 <?= htmlImage ?><br>
  <br>
test for style  
    <table style="background:#ddea95";>
      <tr>
        <th style="border: solid chartreuse; padding:5px; width: 150px; height: 150px;">Logo</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
<br>
<br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th style="background-color: #BCD631; font: bold; border: 1px solid grey; padding: 5px;" width="250px;">Heading 1</th>
        <th style="background-color: #BCD631; font: bold; border: 1px solid grey; padding: 5px;" width="250px;">Heading 2</th>
        <th style="background-color: #BCD631; font: bold; border: 1px solid grey; padding: 5px;" width="250px;">Heading 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;" width="250px;">Row data<br></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;" width="250px;">Row data<br></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;" width="250px;">Row data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;" width="250px;">Row data<br></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;" width="250px;">Row data<br></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;" width="250px;">Row data</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<br>
<br>
<div style="background: #ddea95";><b>Other text to check background format</b><br> </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```
Execution transcript:

[18-06-21 13:30:23:778 CEST] Starting execution
[18-06-21 13:30:23:784 CEST] Session.getActiveUser() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:23:784 CEST] User.getEmail() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:23:926 CEST] GmailApp.getAliases() [0.14 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:23:928 CEST] Logger.log([[alias1, alias2, alias3], []]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:047 CEST] DriveApp.getFileById([10OgwTmtVp5yDKHdC7P1K2KBEMuEbn6YW]) [0.116 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:048 CEST] File.getMimeType() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:049 CEST] File.getAs([image/png]) [0.001 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:050 CEST] File.getBlob() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:148 CEST] UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipMkQrHJPYe935uC-Rap5qVqNaLdUs6rp38yVaw]) [0.097 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:157 CEST] HTTPResponse.getContent() [0.008 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:272 CEST] HtmlService.createTemplate([10,60,33,68,79,67,84,89,80,69,32,104,116,109,108,62,10,60,104,116,109,108,32,108,97,110,103,61,34,101,110,34,62,10,32,32,60,104,101,97,100,62,10,32,32,60,109,101,116,97,32,99,104,97,114,115,101,116,61]...) [0.002 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:273 CEST] Function.apply([[]]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:273 CEST] Logger.log([imgType = image/png
 imgBlob1  = Blob, []]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:276 CEST] HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile([text]) [0.002 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:277 CEST] Function.apply([[]]) [0.001 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:278 CEST] HtmlService.createHtmlOutput() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:280 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([<!DOCTYPE html>
]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:280 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  include styles html from another file with forced printing jquery <br>
  1 ]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:281 CEST] HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile([LogoStyles]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:281 CEST] HtmlOutput.getContent() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:282 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([ <br> <br>
]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:283 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([  </head>

  <body style="Background: white;"> 
  include imgBlob1 from script with jquery <br>
  1 ]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:284 CEST] HtmlOutput.appendUntrusted([Blob]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:284 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([  <br>
]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:285 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([  <br>
  include imgBlob1 from script with img tags <br>
  1 <img src=imgBlob1 />
  <br>
  <br>
  include image from Drive with img tags and url<br>
  1 <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=do]...) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:286 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([<br>
]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:287 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([  <br>
  include imgPng from script with jquery<br>
  1 ]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:288 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([<br>
]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:288 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([  2 ]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:289 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([<br>
]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:290 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([  3 ]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:291 CEST] HtmlOutput.appendUntrusted([Blob]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:291 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([<br>
]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:292 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([  <br>
  include htmlImage from script with jquery
  1 ]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:293 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([<br>
]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:294 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([  2 ]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:295 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([<br>
]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:295 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([  3 ]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:296 CEST] HtmlOutput.appendUntrusted([<img src="data:image/pgn; base64,https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipMkQrHJPYe935uC-Rap5qVqNaLdUs6rp38yVaw" />]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:297 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([<br>
]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:298 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([  <br>
test for style  
    <table style="background:#ddea95";>
      <tr>
        <th style="border: solid chartreuse; padding:5px; width: 150px; height: 150px;">Logo</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
<b]...) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:299 CEST] HtmlOutput.append([]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:299 CEST] HtmlOutput.getContent() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:301 CEST] Utilities.newBlob([<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  include styles html from another file with forced printing jquery <br>
  1  <br> <br>
  </head>

  <body style="Background: white;"> 
  in, ]...) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:302 CEST] Blob.getAs([application/pdf]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:302 CEST] Blob.setName([text for image]) [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:304 CEST] Blob.getName() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:24:304 CEST] Blob.getContentType() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:25:202 CEST] DriveApp.createFile([Blob]) [0.899 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:25:203 CEST] Session.getActiveUser() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:25:203 CEST] User.getEmail() [0 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:25:405 CEST] GmailApp.createDraft([alias1, test, this is a test, {htmlBody=<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  include styles html from another file with forced printing jquery <br>
  }]...) [0.201 seconds]
[18-06-21 13:30:25:408 CEST] Execution succeeded [1.477 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Welcome. Stack Snippets only should be used for executable HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: Please checkout [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) and add the error messages that you get and the execution transcript.

Comment: It seems that ``htmlImage`` is not used.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. If you tell me how to add pictures and documents I'd be happy to show you how the email and pdf are looking.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In your script, ``photosUrl`` of ``htmlImage`` is not the base64 value. And the mimeType is ``image/pgn``. Is this ``image/png``? And you can see the document of Class HtmlTemplate at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template If these are not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer

doGet is a reserved function name. I don't think that is a good idea to use that name for other purposes than those described on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web